# Javascript file not being able to make an Ajax call to laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hi I was hoping someone can help me.  my root folder for my app is cloudapp.azure.com/index.php.  cloudapp.azure.com/ is my public folder.     So all my views are being rendered like so cloudapp.azure.com/index.php/welcome1 from my routes and controllers.  It all workrs fine.

```
Route::post('/welcome1a', [
    'uses'=>'UserController@postRegister',
    'as' => 'register',
]);

Route::post('/welcome1', [
    'uses'=>'UserController@postRegister1',
    'as' => 'register1',
]);

public function postRegister1(Request $request){

   $data1 = $request->all();
   $data = JSON.parse($data1);
   return response()->json(['result' => 'data1']);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is I will be working on phone gap so my views need to be in html.  My HTML files are stored in my public folder (ie cloudapp.azure.com/) so a view will be like cloudapp.azure.com/register.html.

I am trying to send data from cloudapp.azure.com/js/script1.js in my cloudapp.azure.com/register.html view like so to the url that is recognised by my laravel application;

```
 $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           data: details,               
           dataType: "json",   
           success: function(result) {

                    console.log('result'); 

           }
        });
```

but it seems that the js file and the url are not communicating to each other.  Is my file structure wrong?  when I use blade view to do an Ajax call its fine but with my html files calling the url via ajax, it doesnt work.  Even when I try to get my old laravel views via;

$.get("cloudapp.azure.com/index.php/welcome1"); it doesnt work.

I have triend making the ajax call to the following urls;

cloudapp.azure.com/index.php/welcome1

index.php/welcome1

and /welcome1.

There are no errors, but just not communication to each other.

If anyone can help you will be a LIFE SAVER

Comment: have you tried adding an `error:` and console logging the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function postRegister1(Request $request){
   $data1 = $request->all();
   $data = json_decode($data1);
   return response()->json(['result' => 'data1']);
}
```

JSON.parse is javaScript not PHP.

json_decode() is what you use in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

But you shouldn't have to json_decode it either, $request->all() returns an array of the posted values.

I would say, remove the whole json stuff and then see if your ajax call is getting back the return value.

```
public function postRegister1(Request $request){
   return response()->json(['result' => 'testing...']);
}
```

Then go from there...

Comment: Thanks you so much cmac, youre a star.  My first successful ajax call from two technologies, JS and Laravel came from you.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a JS function `JSON.parse` in PHP.

So instead do

```
public function postRegister1(Request $request){
    return response()->json([ 'result' => $request->all() ]);
}
```

Or if you simply return just an array, laravel will automatically cast it into JSON for you

```
public function postRegister1(Request $request){
    return [ 'result' => $request->all() ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the <base> tag on your <head>